# What is the use of related fields in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

Can someone explain to me something about related fields. For example -

- How it was used
- How it can be helped
- For which kind of scenario I should use fields.related

If anybody can provide a small example for real use of fields.related I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It lets you pull a field from a related table. You can find more details in the [developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#relational-types), and one example to look at is the `order_partner_id` field of the `sale_order_line` class. In version 5.14, that's at line 806 of `addons/sale/sale.py`.

I often find that I want to display a field in a list, but it's on a parent record instead of the actual table that I'm listing.

Comment: I was thinking the same, I've tried the example from developer book too, its great, in prior version I use to achieve this by function field - great to have related fields now - it works upto n level ! bingo !!! - Thanks

Answer (score 8):

When using a related field you have to first select which field to be related. For example I'm creating a new module for adding student details. Here the student is actually the partner.  So `_rec_name='partner_id'` is taken.In `res.partner` you may have seen the `ref` field. The value in the `ref` field is taken as the `internal_number` for the student module.

So what we do here is

```
class student(osv.osv):
    _name='student'
    _rec_name='partner_id'
    _columns ={
           'partner_id':fields.many2one('res.partner','Name'),
           'internal_number':fields.related(
                   'partner_id',
                   'ref',
                   type='char',
                   size=16,
                   string='Internal Number',
                   ),
           }
```

If the field we want to show as related field is a selection field, then you have to provide `type='selection'`, and `selection=[(case1,case1),(case2,case2),...]`, a list of tuples. If it is a many2one field, then `type='many2one'` and `relation='model_name'`.

Comment: 'country_id':fields.related('partner_id', 'country_id', type='many2one',relation='res.country', string='Country'),

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example in OpenERP developer documentation, in database normalization it's called [Transitive dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency).

Answer (score 1):

related fields leads the control to another table the parent table wil have a onetomany relation with the child table and the child table have a manytoone relation towards the parent table.
eg: the account.invoice to account.invoice.line  with the following field

'invoice_line': fields.one2many('account.invoice.line', 'invoice_id', 'Invoice Lines', readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]}),

and account.invoice.line relates to account.invoice with the following code in reverse.

'invoice_id': fields.many2one('account.invoice', 'Invoice Reference', ondelete='cascade', select=True),